# Moving Black and White Balls

Tags: java, swing

I'm kind of new to Java and OO programming, here is the code of moving black and white balls problem. First let me explain the program that I want in the output: there are n balls(for example 6 balls) on the window, one black and one white, in each move we only are allowed to move just one ball and ***this movement should be shown on the screen***, and at the end all the white balls should be on one side and all the black balls should be on the other side. Here is an example of six balls:

[image]

I have written the program and it seems working good and no flaws in the algorithm, but my problem is that I can't show animation of the movement of the balls, in each movement one ball should swap its place with its neighbor ball, but all I get is the final arrangements of the balls. Please someone help me with the animation part. I would be really thankful for that.

code:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import javax.swing.*;

public class DrawPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener
{
Timer myTimer = new Timer(2000, this);
public static final int NUMBER_OF_CIRCLES = 10; //number of circles which are to moved
static int[] circles = new int[NUMBER_OF_CIRCLES];

public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    int x = 0; //start point of circles;
    int length = 40; //diagonal of the circles

    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    Ellipse2D circle;

    //painting n circles based on the array
    for(int index = 0; index<10; index++)
    {
        if(circles[index] == 0){ //if the element of the arrayy is 0 then draw a void circle

            circle = new Ellipse2D.Double(x, 120, length, length);
            g2.draw(circle);
        }
        else if(circles[index] == 1){ //if the element of the array is 1 them draw a filled circle
            circle = new Ellipse2D.Double(x, 120, length, length);
            g2.fill(circle);
        }
        x += 45; //increas start pont of the next circle 45 pixles
    }
    myTimer.start();
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    int tmp; //template for swaping elements
    int condition; //condition of the forS

    arrayFill(circles); //fills the array based on the writen method, one 1 and one 0 like: 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1

    //here is the part which works good, it changes palces of an elemen at time.
    //at the end of this part the array would be like: 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
    if(NUMBER_OF_CIRCLES % 2 == 0)
        condition = circles.length/2 -1;
    else
        condition = circles.length/2;
    for(int i = circles.length-1, k = 1; i>condition; i--, k++)
    {
        for(int j = i - k; j<i ;j++)
        {
            tmp = circles[j];
            circles[j] = circles[j+1];
            circles[j+1] = tmp;
            //if we call arrayPrint method it will print the array but I don't know why repaint is not working here
            //arrayPrint(circles);
            repaint();
        }
    }
}

//fills the array, one 1 and one 0. Example: 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1
public static void arrayFill(int[] array)
{
    for(int i = 0; i<array.length; i++)
    {
        if( i%2 == 0)
            array[i] = 0;
        else 
            array[i] = 1;
    }
}

}//end of class
```

And the main Class:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
public class BlackAndWhiteBallsMoving {

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    DrawPanel myPanel = new DrawPanel();
    JFrame myFrame = new JFrame();

    myFrame.add(myPanel);
    myFrame.setSize(600, 500);
    myFrame.setTitle("Black And White Balls Moving");
    myFrame.setVisible(true);
    myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

}//end of class
```

Comment: You're calling `arrayFill(circles)` with each tick, so you're always starting over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The events triggered by the `Timer` are performed on the same event thread as the repaints. Calling `repaint` does not actively perform a paint event, rather it queues one for later. When you call your repaints from within the timer event, they will only get executed once the timer event is completed.

What you need to do is refactor your loop so that only a single swap is performed each time the timer triggers. I've done this for you as an example:

```
public class DrawPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    public static final int NUMBER_OF_CIRCLES = 10;

    Timer myTimer = new Timer(500, this);
    int[] circles = new int[NUMBER_OF_CIRCLES];

    public DrawPanel() {
        arrayFill(circles);

        if(NUMBER_OF_CIRCLES % 2 == 0) {
            condition = circles.length/2 -1;
        } else {
            condition = circles.length/2;
        }

        i = circles.length - 1;
        k = 1;

        myTimer.start();
    }

    int i, j, k;
    int condition;
    boolean outer = true;

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(outer) {
            if(i > condition) {
                j = i - k;      // set j
                outer = false;  // and move to the inner loop swap
            } else {
                myTimer.stop(); // the outer loop is done so stop the timer
            }
        }
        if(!outer) {
            int tmp = circles[j];
            circles[j] = circles[j+1];
            circles[j+1] = tmp;
            repaint();

            j++;
            if(j >= i) {
                i--;
                k++;
                outer = true; // move to the outer condition
            }                 // next time the timer triggers
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        int x = 0;
        int length = 40;

        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        Ellipse2D circle;
        for(int index = 0; index<10; index++) {
            if(circles[index] == 0){
                circle = new Ellipse2D.Double(x, 120, length, length);
                g2.draw(circle);
            } else if(circles[index] == 1){
                circle = new Ellipse2D.Double(x, 120, length, length);
                g2.fill(circle);
            }
            x += 45;
        }
        //myTimer.start();
    }

    public static void arrayFill(int[] array) {
        for(int i = 0; i<array.length; i++) {
            if( i%2 == 0) {
                array[i] = 0;
            } else {
                array[i] = 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(I'm sure it could be factored another way.)

Also:

- I added `@Override` annotations which you should use. Doing so will warn you when you make certain mistakes. (Like misspelling a method name or incorrectly declaring its signature.)
- I moved `circles` to an instance variable because I don't see a reason it should be static. It is part of the state of the `DrawPanel` instance.
- I created a constructor which initializes variables such as `circles`.
- `paintComponent` is a `protected` method and it should remain so unless there is a reason to promote it to `public`.

(I removed your comments and changed the bracing style just to condense the code for my answer.)

As a side note, you should read the tutorial [Initial Threads](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html). You are not creating your GUI on the Swing event thread. Basically you need to wrap your code in `main` inside a call to `invokeLater`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // create and show your GUI
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The basic problem is in your `actionPerformed` method.  Your two `for` loops are rearranging the array to its final arrangement very quickly.  Each loop iteration will take a matter of nanoseconds to milliseconds to complete (it depends on how the repaint() method works).  The entire process is finished in less than 50 milliseconds or so.  That's too fast for your eyes to keep up.

Basically, the repaint() method is working, but it's working too fast for human eyes to keep up.

If you break up the `for` loops into something that does one step of the algorithm each time it's called, you can trigger that from a timer and see the animation at a human-detectable speed.

Answer (score 0):

add a paint thread. it should always call repaint() like,

```
new Thread(){  // this can be started on main or constructor of object
 public void run(){
    while(true){
       repaint();
       try {
         Thread.sleep(50);
        } catch(Exception e){ } 
     }
   }
  }.start();
```

and then, on action performed, mark moving objects like movingObjects, keep a animate_x = 0 and keep a boolean variable like existAnimation

then on paintComponent, increase animate_x

```
animate_x = animate_x + 1;
if (animate_x >= MAX_WIDTH_OF_ANIMATION){
  existAnimation = false;
}
```

and use this existAnimation, animate_x and movingObjects

like,

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    int x = 0; //start point of circles;
    int length = 40; //diagonal of the circles

    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    Ellipse2D circle;

    //painting n circles based on the array
    for(int index = 0; index<10; index++)
    {

        int paint_x = x;
        if (movingObjects.has(circles[index])){
            paint_x += animate_x;
        }
        if(circles[index] == 0){ //if the element of the arrayy is 0 then draw a void circle

            circle = new Ellipse2D.Double(paint_x, 120, length, length);
            g2.draw(circle);
        }
        else if(circles[index] == 1){ //if the element of the array is 1 them draw a filled circle
            circle = new Ellipse2D.Double(paint_x, 120, length, length);
            g2.fill(circle);
        }
        x += 45; //increas start pont of the next circle 45 pixles
    }
    myTimer.start();
}
```